# Not saving product in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom module to save product using API. I have created a model class and write a demo code and call this to my controller

```
class Company_Drop_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function addProducts() {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    try {
        $product
            ->setStoreId(0) //you can set data in store scope
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
            //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
            ->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
            ->setName('test product21') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
            ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
            ->setColor(24)
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
            ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
            ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
            ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
            ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => 999 //qty
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array(2,3)); //assign product to categories
        $product->save();
        echo 'Product saved...';
        //endif;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
    }

    }
```

Controller File

```
class Company_Drop_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function IndexAction() {
       Mage::getModel('drop/product')->addProducts();
    }
}
```

but it is not saving my product

I have debug the code generate the log files I am getting below error
2016-06-14T09:33:19+00:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mdemo`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-06-14 09:33:19', '2016-06-14 09:33:19')

Comment: did you look in the database and the product is not there, or you just don't see it in the admin panel?

Comment: I am not getting in the admin panel didn't check in the database. Yes check in the DB and there is no product

Comment: check in the database if there are new records appearing in `catalog_product_entity` when you run your code

Comment: I have checked the DB there is no product. Is there  anything wrong with my  code

Comment: are you sure your controller is being called?

Comment: Yes I have debug the code only problem is in $product->save();. I am getting my data before use of this save function.

Comment: Thanks for all of your support. I got the answer first of all I was using higher version of mysql and one thing I was using wrong value of attribute set id. there is no code mistake

Comment: I don't think 9 is the default attribute set ID for products, isn't it 4 by default?

Answer (score 1):

You should try by setting up current store as Admin like below at the starting of addproducts() function.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Comment: Already Tried with this but not working. Thanks for your effort

Comment: It worked for me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code in file `Mage::getModel('drop/product')`;

```
<?php
class Company_Drop_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function addProducts()
    {
        $sku = "testsku61";
        $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku, null, 'sku');
        try {
            $attributeSetId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
                    ->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            $product->setStoreId(0) //you can set data in store scope
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
            ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
            ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
            ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
            ->setName('test product21') //product name
            ->setWeight(4.0000)
            ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
            ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
            ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
            ->setColor(24)
            ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
            ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
            ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
            ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
            ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
            ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
            ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
            ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
            ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
            ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
            ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
            ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
            ->setDescription('This is a long description')
            ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
            ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/10243-1.png', array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
            ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => 999 //qty
                )
            )
            ->setCategoryIds(array(2,3)); //assign product to categories
            if($product->getId()) {
                $product->setId($product->getId()); //SKU   
            }else {
                $product->setSku($sku); //SKU   
            }
            $product->save();
            echo 'Product saved...';
        //endif;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Note:** Above code first check **sku** in system if already created then updates product data otherwise create new product in system

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what your code is doing that is different from the question? It's not a very useful answer otherwise.

Comment: Also hint: he says in a comment that the attribute set was wrong

Comment: @Robbie : My code first check sku in system if already created then updates product data otherwise create new product in system

Comment: I know what your code does but others may not, hence the suggestion to improve your answer :-)